# Can't store pig table in hbase

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

While running the local mode in pig, I tried to store a pig table into HBase:

**Creating table from csv:**
`raw_data = LOAD '/home/hfu/data/input.csv`' USING PigStorage( ',' ) AS `(listing_id: chararray, fname: chararray, lname: chararray );`

**Store into HBase:**
`STORE raw_data INTO 'hbase://sample_names`' USING `org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage ('info:fname info:lname');`

**While running the store command, pig is stopping at:**

```
[main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x150ec3d937d000a, negotiated timeout = 90000
```

(log files from master or regionserver displayed nothing)
**What can I do to store a pig table into hbase?**

**I'm using:**
pig-0.15.0
hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2
hadoop-2.6.1

all running on one virtual machine